# DRF relate single field from model

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

Yes, I know there are a lot of questions about DRF serializer relations that are already answered. But non of them could help me or I'm to dump to get it...

I have the following models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    person_id = models.IntegerField()
    birthdate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

Now I want the `birthdate` field from `Person` in `User` like this:

```
{
    "id": 397,
    "name": "name",
    "birthdate": "2015-11-11T00:00:00Z",
    ...
}
```

So I did this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    birthdate = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def get_birthdate(self, obj):
        person = PersonSerializer(Person.objects.get(person_id=obj.pk)).data
        return person['birthdate']
```

It works yea but there has to be a better way. I have multiple fields I want to relate in this way and the result would be awkward code so please help me!

Comment: Any reason why `person_id` not a `ForeignKey(User)`?

Comment: I already tried this. But what do I have to do then in the serializers?

Comment: `birthdate = DateTimeField(source="person_set.birthdate")` should do the trick, where `person_set` needs to be the `related_name` of the foreign key. See [the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) for details. You might also want to use a `OneToOneField`, because currently there can be multiple persons per user.

Comment: `Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'birthdate' on serializer 'UserSerializer'. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the 'User' instance. Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'birthdate'.`

This is what I get

Comment: @dhke I have the deep whis to kiss you :D
The OneToOneField did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: Don't get tangled in the beard, then ;-). I actually thought of that problem too late. The `DateTimeField` over a simple foreign key only works with `many=True` because the schema allows for multiple persons per user. Using a `OneToOneField` solves that problem and also cleans up the schema.

Comment: Yea I see... such a simple thing but if you don't know it...
Do you want to create the answer or should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks again to dhke. He helped me in the comments to find the answer to my question.

The only thing I had to do is adding a `OneToOneField` to `Person`:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    person_id = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='person')
    birthdate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

Then add the following field to `UserSerializer`:

```
birthdate = serializers.DateTimeField(source='person.birthdate')
```

And that is the whole magic.

(I love DRF!)